# No MTA installed, discarding the output

Tags: command-line, cron

The cron is running fine for other shell scripts. But I want to send the custom service status data to aws cloud watch. Below is the job details

```
* * * * * sh ~/myscript.sh
```

I don't want to send mail. The script is manually running and sending the data to cloud watch. The script is working fine on other Linux-OS.
Please let me know the solution.

Comment: An "MTA" is a Message Transfer Agent, part of the email system. Your script generated some output that `cron` wanted to email you. It couldn't. Redirect your script's output to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the error message by sending the output to `/dev/null`. Here's how:

```
* * * * * sh ~/myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

That's all there is to it